# Problem with Python / Multiple Ring Buffer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, importerror

I can't open any Tools that use Python script - and I have no idea about these things. I get the following error note:

[image: Error message]

I don't know anything about the "IT" side of things. Last line of text is "the specified module was not found". Am Using ArcGIS Pro 3.1

Comment: I notice that the error is referring to programs on a D drive. Windows is typically installed on a C drive and so should ArcPro. As a starting point I would uninstall your version and install it correctly on C:\ drive.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than only in a picture.